# Designing a database for "not seen" queries

Tags: mysql, database-design, mongodb

I'm building a large collection of items from which I want to query items that a specific user has *not* seen before. I will need to track, per user, which items s/he has seen.

Currently the *items* are stored in mongodb and the 'seen items' I am planning to store in a mysql database.

I have two questions:

1. How should I design the database of items in order to effectively query for items a certain user has *not* seen?
2. As each user can have 'seen' several thousand items, should each user have its own mysql table or should I just have one large table?

**EDIT**: The items the user get are from the collection of items the user has not seen are selected randomly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data says that you need

```
CREATE TABLE Seen (
    user_id ...,
    item_id ...,
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id, item_id),
    INDEX      (item_id, user_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

That is in addition to table `Users`, with `PRIMARY KEY (user_id)` and `Items` with `PRIMARY KEY (item_id)`.

Items not seen by user 1234:

```
SELECT i.item_id
    FROM Items AS i
    LEFT JOIN Seen AS s  ON  s.item_id = i.item_id
                         AND s.user_id = 1234;
    WHERE s.item_id IS NULL ;
```

You could then `JOIN` to `Users` and/or `Items` to get more info.

Separate tables for separate users -- *NO*.  This is a common question with the same answer every time.